# why this error happens with codeigniter fileupload?

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

this is my upload function

```
public function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('customer_photo'))
    {
              $responce->success = false;
              $responce->data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();            
    }
    else
    {             
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                    $this->_do_resize($data);
    }
       echo json_encode($responce); 
}
```

this is the json what im seeing on firebug console

```
{"success":false,"data":{"error":"<p>The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.&lt;\/p&gt;"}}</p>
```

any idea why its contain `</p>` and these `&lt;\/p&gt;` ?

Regards

Comment: What exactly is your question - why the error happens, or why the error contains `<p>` tags?

Comment: RTM: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html  Under `$this->upload->display_errors()`.

Comment: @pekka what i try to mean is why the json output contains </p>tag and other strange chars

Comment: Please don't try to limit filetype by relying on file extensions. This is not standardised. A JPEG file might be called `x.jpg`, `x.jpeg`, `x.JPE`, `x.pjpeg`, `x.potato` or `x`, depending on the OS and settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html), `$this->upload->display_errors()` wraps the error messages in `<p>` tags.

You can pass parameters for the delimiters, to wrap the errors in what you want.

```
$this->upload->display_errors('', '');
```